# How to add a hyperlink in a Google Sheet using a Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hyperlink

My sheet contains a dropdown for the selection of the system in column "A" and the ticket ID will be entered in column "B".

If e.g. OTRS is selected in column "A", the ticket ID should be displayed as a hyperlink in column "B"
e.g. '= HYPERLINK' + '("http: //otrs/otrs/index.pl? Action = AgentTicketZoom; TicketNumber =' + activeCellValue + '"; "' + activeCellValue + '")'

If Zendesk is selected in column "A", the hyperlink should lead to http: // zendesk ...

Does anyone have an idea or a code example?

i tried this
but i got an error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
> InsertLink  @ Code.gs:3

```js
 function InsertLink(e)
    {
      var actSht = e.source.getActiveSheet();
      if (actSht.getName() == ['SheetName']){

      var activeCell = actSht.getActiveCell(); 

      var activeCellValue = e.value;

      var column = activeCell.getColumn();
      var colNums  = [1]; 
      if(colNums.indexOf(column) == -1) return; 

      var row = activeCell.getRow();
      if(row < 2)   return; //If header row then return

      var length = String(activeCellValue).length;

      if (!e.value)
      {
        activeCell.setValue()
      }
      else if(length > 4)
      {
        activeCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK' + '("http://otrs/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketNumber='+activeCellValue+'";"'+activeCellValue+'")'        );
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You can use nested `IF` formulas, or write your own formula with Apps Script: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Hyperlink` function which can set dynamic link based on the cell value as following:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&E2 &"?p="&E2&"&.tsrc=fin-srch",F2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason the script you have shared returns the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined InsertLink @ Code.gs:3` error is because it is an *installable* `onEdit` *trigger* and you are not using it as such.

**This means the following:**

1. the function *will run each time a new edit is made* in the spreadsheet;
2. you will have to install it by going to **Triggers** > **Add trigger** and create a new trigger with the following settings:

[image: onedit trigger settings]

3. you will have to adapt the script such that it matches **your needs accordingly**;

- the script will run if the active sheet's name is `SheetName` - so depending on your sheet, you will have to modify the name in the script;

```
if (actSht.getName() == ['SheetName'])
```

- the `HYPERLINK` formula will be set only if the cell which has been edited has a value of length larger than 4 characters:

```
activeCell.setValue('=HYPERLINK' + '("http://otrs/otrs/index.pl?Action=AgentTicketZoom;TicketNumber='+activeCellValue+'";"'+activeCellValue+'")');
```

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).